# Will bootstrap scrollspy work with btn-group?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use the scrollspy feature in Bootstrap, but I'd rather use buttons and btn-group buttons than what I get with navbar.  Yes, I could probably restyle the navbar to look like a button group, but, before I do that, it seemed worth checking whether scrollspy will work with button groups.  (I've tried, unsuccessfully, but that doesn't mean I've got the right approach.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/fcn78/

I took a standard btn-group, and added these extra properties:

```
  <div class="btn-group affix-top"  data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="10">
```

where data-offset-top is the distance you need to scroll before the button group is affixed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, I've moved on to a different approach.